# MDSheet add-on plugin used for Openoffice spreardsheet. Facing run-time error

Tags: openoffice.org, add-on, openoffice-writer

I have installed the plug-in (old version) and tried creating class but facing runtime error.
http://ssaapp.di.uminho.pt/twiki/bin/view/Main/Software
This is the website link.

```
Sub btn_add_class_click
  Dim oDoc As Object
  oDoc = ThisComponent
  Dim oRange As Object
  oRange = GetSelectedRange(oDoc)
  If (Not IsNull(oRange)) Then
    Dim MDSheetService As Object
    MDSheetService = createUnoService("MDSheet.ClassSheet")
    'MDSheetService.modelAddColumn(0,oRange.RangeAddress.StartColumn)
    'MsgBox "Cell (" & oRange.RangeAddress.StartColumn & "," & oRange.RangeAddress.StartRow & ")"
    Dim oResult As Object
    oResult = ShowAddClassDialog(oDoc)
    If (Not IsNull(oResult)) Then
      Dim oAddr As Object
      oAddr = oRange.RangeAddress
      If (oResult(2) = 0) Then ' no expansion
        **MDSheetService.modelAddClass(oResult(0),oResult(1), _**
            oAddr.StartColumn, oAddr.StartRow, _
            oAddr.EndColumn, oAddr.EndRow)
      Else ' expansion
        MDSheetService.modelAddExpClass(oResult(0),oResult(1), _
            oAddr.StartColumn, oAddr.StartRow, _
            oAddr.EndColumn, oAddr.EndRow, _
            oResult(2) - 1)
      End If
    End If
  Else
    MsgBox "No valid selection."
  End If
End Sub
```

The error is marked with `**`.

I am using this add-on in linux ubuntu 14.04 and openoffice version 4.1.1

Please throw some suggestion how I can debug this error?

Answer (score 0):

Well, [xray](http://bernard.marcelly.perso.sfr.fr/index2.html) is a good debugging tool, although it sounds like you may be running into a problem with the MDSheet library.  Please post the runtime error message.

The page you linked says that MDSheet `was only made available for demonstration purposes.`  Perhaps there is a missing library dependency.  The only way to find out may be to ask the author, as recommended on the web page.